# How to store JSON data in database(heidiSQL) using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have data in JSON format. I am able to create object in javascript for that as below.

```
var text = '{"title":"abc","desc":"pqr" ,"img":"mno"}';
obj = JSON.parse(text);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
obj.title + " " + obj.desc;
```

Now, I just want to store the value of that JSON object in  database(heidiSQL).

My table's attributes are as follows:
1)title,
2)description,
3)image

Comment: Send the json string through ajax, then decode it in server side

Comment: i don't know how to do that

Comment: Are you using PHP?

Comment: No.. in server side I am using JAVA

Comment: Do you mean JSP? Java cannot receive ajax request, as I know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115399/discussion-between-ravi-s-and-super-cool-handsome-gel-boy).